Compare values in wix installer (.wxs file)
I have a scenario where in, if the version is less than 3.6 then I want to install something and if it is greater than 3.6, then I want to install something else. I have read through the post if else in wix installer the accepted answer, I went through the link also. When I use = symbol, its building fine. But if I use < or > symbols, it says "An illegal version was found in the expression". Please help. Is it even possible to do something like this in the wix installer?
Here is what I have in the Bundle.wxs
<?define ProductVersion = "3.5.33"?>

    <?if $(var.ProductVersion)<3.6 ?>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="SQL2017Express"></PackageGroupRef>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="SQLNativeClient"/>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="PharmSpecMsi"/>
            <ExePackage Id="AccessDatabaseEngineInstaller"
                        SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe"
                        InstallCommand="/quiet"
                        Compressed="yes" />
      <?else?>
      <!-- Install SQL SERVER 2022. -->
      <?endif?>


Try to specify full version numbers, e. g. "3.5.33.0" and "3.6.0.0". I'm not sure whether the preprocessor actually does correct version number comparison and not just literal string comparison, but the error message seems to imply that it does the former.
